# Always start batch file with /u?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I recently read that starting `cmd.exe` with the `/u` flag causes it to output to files in unicode format, but how would I start batch files like this? To clarify, I don't mean start *other* batch files from an already running batch file, I mean click on a batch file and it automatically runs with `/u`? Since the purpose of starting a batch file with /u is to output files in unicode, I'm looking for a way to either do this in code or start the batch file with the flag always, which isn't possible. Another solution could be if you can detect whether /u is on or not in code, in which case if it's off than I can just do `start /u this.bat`?

Comment: I'm not sure but can't you right-click on the batch file and see if there is an option/setting where you can specify run parameters? You could also create a shortcut to your batch file with the `/u` flag in the target.

Comment: @KristerAndersson I can't do the first thing but I know you can make a shortcut for it, I was trying to avoid that and have a standalone batch file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379888/pass-parameter-to-bat-file-and-run-by-double-click

Comment: I can't make a shortcut, what I'm trying to figure out is if there is an alternative to outputting in unicode that you can do in code, I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
start "UNICODE" cmd /u
```

Put that line into a batchfile and add a link (or even that batch itself) to the desktop. You can then start it with a double-click.

**edit:** after a long walk with my dog, i assume this does not help you
But maybe this one helps:

```
if "%1" == "/unicode" goto begin
start "Unicode-Window" cmd /u /k "%~dpf0 /unicode %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9"
exit 
:begin
shift

rem start of my batchfilever
echo %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

The Idea is: I don't know, if this window was startet with /u, but I don't care.
I just start the very same file  (%~dpf0) in a new window, which IS started with /u and close the current window. Of course this would mean an enless loop, which I avoid with the additional parameter /unicode.
The second run detects that parameter (which has to be the first one) and deletes it (shift).
Just add this "header" (until the rem-line) to your Batch.

Comment: This is JUST what I was looking for, the only thing I had to change was `%~dpf0` to `%0` because it wasn't working for some reason, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the way all batch file will run, you need to modify the windows registry.

change the value to the key  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command(Default)   from

```
"%1" %*
```

to

```
"cmd /U /C %1" %*
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it to be confined to the batch file because my computer isn't going to be the only one it's going to be running on and I can't change it on those other computers

Comment: @leaf68 A batch file cannot retroactively modify the way it's launched unless it re-launches itself from within the script. Would changing the codepage (`chcp 65001`) work for you?

Comment: Relaunching itself works fine, doesn't `chcp 65001` just change the encoding of what CMD displays, or does it also change the file output?